# Multiple transformations Java Stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of String, and I have methods defined to tranform each of the element in the list, eg. convert each string to int, add 'x' to the int and convert the int into a String. I need a final list of tranformed String.

I wanted to do it using Java stream api.

This is the example code

```
private void test(){
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    mylist.add("1");
    mylist.add("2");
    mylist.add("3");
    //need list of String like [11,12,13] after transforming each element through the below methods.


}

private int inttoString(String s){
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}

private int addX(int st){
    return st+10;
}

private String convertToStr(int s){
    return Integer.toString(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple [**map**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) like this :

```
List<String> result = mylist.stream()
        .map(s -> inttoString(s))
        .map(s -> addX(s))
        .map(s -> convertToStr(s))
        .collect(toList());
```

Or in one map :

```
List<String> result = mylist.stream()
        .map(s -> convertToStr( addX( inttoString(s) ) ))
        .collect(toList());
```

Or without your methods :

```
List<String> result = mylist.stream()
        .map(s -> String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(s) + 10))
        .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not need use these methods to perform so simple operations.
Java 8 stream functions allow to do that in a concise and clear way :

```
List<String> list = mylist.stream()
                          .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                          .map(x -> x + 10)
                          .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: not much difference but was just thinking another variant would be --> `mylist.stream() .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) .map(x -> x + 10) .mapToObj(String::valueOf) .collect(Collectors.toList());` . benefit being that no boxing and unboxing is performed.

Comment: @Aominè It is a little change and it is efficient for larger lists. I take it :) Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Also, with the edit `.mapToObj(Integer::toString)` would also be valid. so the statement _Integer.toString() is ambiguous if you use it in a method reference_ is no longer true.

Comment: @Aominè Right. It is often the problem as I modify a "long" answer. I have to check all the content to ensure consistency. What I don't perform at each time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply as many `map` operations to a stream as you like.

e.g.,

```
foo.stream()
   .map(functionA)
   .map(functionB)
   .map(functionC)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

These are applied to elements in the encounter order of the underlying stream.